# Angular Property Data Comes Back Empty

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display some buttons to the screen. I don't get any errors but, it looks like there is no data and the HTML is not rendering. My code is below, I couldn't figure out what the problem is. What should I change?

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
                        <button mat-button class="green fuse-white-fg" *ngFor="let prm of cell" [value]="prm">{{prm.warehouse.Cells?.CellBarcode}}</button>
                      </div>
```

TS:

```
export class WarehouseDetailComponent {
    warehouse: IWarehouse;
    cell: ICell[];


    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ICell>;
    selection = new SelectionModel<ICell>(true, []);

    constructor(private _stockService: StockService, private _router: Router) {
        _stockService.onWarehouseDetailChanged.subscribe(
            (response: IWarehouse) => {
                this.warehouse = response;
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.Cells);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>
                    this.filterPredicate(data, filter);

                }
        );
        
    }
```

IWarehouse interface:

```
export interface IWarehouse {
    Cells?: ICell[];
}
```

ICell interface:

```
export interface ICell {
    CellId?: number;
    CellName?: string;
    CellBarcode?: string;
   
}
```

Comment: You seem to be looping over the `cell` array but I can't see where it is getting assigned to something. Moreover `ICell` doesn't have a `warehouse` property so `prm.warehouse` is probably undefined

Comment: I tried it again by using `<button mat-button class="green fuse-white-fg" *ngFor="let prm of cell" [value]="prm">{{prm.CellBarcode}}</button>`
but it is still empty.

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to your `cell` property?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem can be related with lifecycle, try it:

```html
<div fxLayout="column" class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
                        <button mat-button class="green fuse-white-fg" *ngFor="let prm of cell" [value]="prm">{{prm?.warehouse?.Cells?.CellBarcode}}</button>
                      </div>
```

```js
export class WarehouseDetailComponent {
    warehouse: IWarehouse;
    cell: ICell[];


    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ICell>;
    selection = new SelectionModel<ICell>(true, []);

    constructor(private _stockService: StockService, private _router: Router) { 
    }
    
    ngOnInit(){
        this._stockService.onWarehouseDetailChanged.subscribe(
            (response: IWarehouse) => {
                this.warehouse = response;
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response.Cells);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>
                    this.filterPredicate(data, filter);

                }
        );    
    }
}
```